# If sign up error occurs in Devise Sign up form redirect to same route rails 4

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise, error-messages-for

I have customized the devise sign up form to show up in my custom page . I am showing up my registration form in the home page. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0815w1h9b0.

I need to show up the Error at the Top of the Form itself. If i click on Submit button without filling up the fields it is redirecting to the '**/users**' page with errors. I need to show it up the errors in the same page where i have the form.

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource_class 
     User 
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception  
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?


        def configure_devise_params
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
          u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :dob, :token, :contact_number, :profile_by, :email, :password, :password_confirmation ,:religion_id ,:caste_id ,:sub_caste_id)
            end
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
          u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :dob, :contact_number, :profile_by, :email, :current_password)
          end   
        end
     # REDIRECT USER TO OUR CUSTOM PATH AFTER LOGIN
        def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
            root_path
          end
        def after_update_path_for(resource)
          show_profile_path
        end
        # REDIRECT USER TO OUR CUSTOM PATH AFTER LOGOUT
        def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
            root_path
        end
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  devise_for :users
  get '/home'=>'home#index', as: 'home_path'
end
```

**new.html.erb** under Devise Views

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.hidden_field :token, value: rand(13 ** 13), autofocus: true %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :First_Name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter First Name' %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :Last_Name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter Last Name' %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :date_of_birth %>
                    <%= f.text_field :dob, class: 'datepicker', placeholder: 'Enter Date of Birth' %>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('.datepicker').datepicker()
                        </script>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :gender %>
                    <%= f.radio_button :gender, '1', :checked => true %> <span class="radio-names">Male</span>
                    <%= f.radio_button :gender, '2' %><span class="radio-names">Female</span>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter Email Address' %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :profile_password %>
                    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Enter Password' %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :confirm_password %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Enter Confirm Password' %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :register_for %>
                    <%= f.select :profile_by, [['Myself', 1], ['Dad', 2], ['Mom', 3], ['Brother', 4], ['Sister', 5], ['Relative', 6], ['Son', 7], ['Daughter', 8]],{},{class: 'select_tag'} %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :contact_number %>
                    <%= f.text_field :contact_number, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter Contact Number +91' %>
                </div>


                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :Religion %>
                    <%= f.select :religion_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Religion.all, :id, :religion),{},{class: 'select_tag'} %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :caste %>
                    <%= f.select :caste_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Caste.all, :id, :caste_name),{},{class: 'select_tag'} %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :subcaste %>
                    <%= f.select :sub_caste_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Subcaste.all, :id, :sub_caste_name),{},{class: 'select_tag'} %>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Register", class: 'register_button' %>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

Help me how to display up the errors at the same page if some error occurs at sign up process.

Comment: you are redirecting different page when get sign up errors ?

Comment: I am not redirecting. On success alone i redirect to root_path. The Validations after click on submit button is working but i need to show it on the same page .

Comment: yes that's correct, when gets error it moves from `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` to `http://localhost:3000/users` with errors and form.

Comment: Ya my errors are be shown in the http://localhost:3000/users page . I need to show it in the same page where i have the form . I have my form in http://localhost:3000/home

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to overwrite devise controller
Try this:

create class in lib folder and overwrite devise failure method there like this:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
     #new_user_registration_path or your_path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
     http_auth
   else
     redirect
   end
 end
end
```

And put this config/initializers/devise.rb

```
 config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

One more thing you have to auto load lib file like:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

put this line at config/application.rb

Comment: Hi Thorin, the def redirect_url is there where i have to write my redirect url http://localhost:3000/home . Am i right

Comment: How i need to create the class in lib folder .

Comment: replace #your path with the signup path

Comment: just add custom_failure.rb file in lib folder and paste class code there

Comment: I have applied all your coding that you have made and restarted my server too but still i redirect to the http://localhost:3000/users with the following errors. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0915w1rgab

Comment: Hi is there any method available for redirection purpose

Comment: add debugger in redirect_url method and check that method is calling or not

Comment: debugger method means how can i add it . Please let me know step by step bro.

Answer (score 0):

when gets error it moves from `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` to `http://localhost:3000/users with errors` and form.

If you looked at the controllers in `https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb`

In `registrations_controller.rb`

Locate `create` method

```
 def create
    [..................]
       else
         set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
         expire_data_after_sign_in!
         respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    [..................]
```

You can easily see that when there are errors it will respond to resource, in your case it is `users`.

There are two options

1. Either you override registrations controller and add redirection in the above lines.
2. OR you can create strategy for Devise.

Comment: Hi bro, how i need to create strategy for Devise. i have created Custom Failure also for devise and i am getting the same issue .

Comment: @NareshKumar.P This [Link](https://gist.github.com/r00k/906356) will help you to create custom strategy as per your requirement. and you can also take help from this too [Link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb).

Comment: Is there any way to rectify the @Thorin method of redirection i am unable to get the result with that.